# drawing roc curve analysis

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I tried to draw the roc curve with latex but i didn't find any solution. Can any one help please. My code doesn't work and i didn't find a curve like this figure. Could you help me please. Thank you in advance [image: roc curve analysis]

Comment: No idea what an roc curve is, but can you show the code you have that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with something like this, and improve upon it until you get the complete output you want. The PGFPlots manual has much more to learn from.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{filecontents}{mydata.dat}
x      f(x)
0.0    0.0
0.0    0.1
0.0    0.2
0.1    0.2
0.1    0.3
0.1    0.4
0.1    0.5
0.2    0.5
0.3    0.5
0.3    0.6
0.4    0.6
0.4    0.7 
0.5    0.7
0.5    0.8
0.6    0.8
0.7    0.8
0.8    0.8
0.8    0.9
0.9    0.9
0.9    1.0
1.0    1.0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  title={My ROC},
  xlabel={some $x$},
  ylabel={Advance},
]
\addplot [blue,mark=diamond*] table {mydata.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]